# Is it possible to develop multi-platform game for mobile devices by using Construct 2?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-engine, multiplatform

I have been searching some tools for multi-platform game engine which support for all mobile devices(Android, IOS, Windows, Blackberry). I found Construct 2 game engine but I am worried about weather this will support for all mobiles or not? Is it possible to build game by using phonegap? Anybody help me to get more idea about this. Or else please suggest me other tools which we can develop games from scratch HTML5, Javascript.
While searching I found these engines 1. Quintus engine 2. Construct 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you checked this out:  https://www.scirra.com/
But it says here that you can develop for Windows, iOS, Android, Blackberry.

Here are a list of games made with Construct 2: 
http://www.scirra.com/arcade

If you're still unsure about the engine, I recommend running simulators for each OS on your PC (using Virtual Box or etc..)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have check with https://www.scirra.com/. How to build for all platforms? can we use HTML5, JS for developing?

Comment: Yes you can, you can also build games without any coding knowledge. For more info, check out: https://www.scirra.com/construct2

Comment: Yes I have gone through document. Its fantastic. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can, but via Web technology.

But before dig in deep, I'll say that, C2 is RAD drag-n-drop gamedev tool like GameMaker by YoYoGames, but not an engine. It has It's own runtime and plugin environment but It almost not support code in javascript directly but require to make *Event-Sheets* for programming game logics (Plugins will be coded with javascript).

As I know, Construct 2 runtime and plugins are based on JavaScript, then first exports the project to web platform or similar thing, and Uses some good wrapper. I don't know deeply about this topic but it would be wrappers...

When you export via the Cordova option, You'll install Intel XDK and import the exported project directory to the Intel XDK, add some settings, and cloud-build.

See [this tutorial article](http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/71/how-to-export-to-mobile-with-phonegap) for how to export to mobile devices (Android, iOS).

On other platforms, for example C2 uses NW.js for windows, which is node.js + Webkit, and for platforms which support web technology natively (Windows Store, BlackBerry, Tizen, etc...) It might (I don't know in deep about this) export with suited settings for that platform. Quite convenient.

See [this tutorial article](http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/993/how-to-export-windows-store-apps) for how to export to Windows store platform (phone, desktop).